# collectionView does not scroll when few item exist

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uirefreshcontrol

I want to get collectionView scroll even though only 2 items are contained in it. I want to implement `UIRefreshControl` when pulling it. Any idea why it does not move?

[image]

Comment: Make sure its contentSize is  larger than its bound size.

Answer (score 1):

Scroll views only scroll, if their content size is bigger then the currently visible frame.

You can still implement pull-to-refresh without using `UIRefreshControl`, you just have to observe user's scroll event. The basic workflow is this:

- Add your "refresh control" (a simple view) above your collection view
- Implement the `scrollViewDidEndDragging(_:willDecelerate:)` delegate method to check the content offset
- If the content offset is greater than a pre-defined value (let's say 40 points), you trigger the refreshing code

[This article contains a full example, check it out!](http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/how-to-add-a-custom-pull-to-refresh-in-your-ios-application/)